# Can anyone please tell me why an object's function expression makes use of 'this' keyword to access the object's member variables?

Tags: javascript, this

For instance, consider the code snippet :

```
var john=
{  fullname: 'john smith',
  bill:[124,48,268,180,42],
  tip:[],final:[],
  calcTip:function()
  {
    for(var i =0;i<this.bill.length;i++)
    {
      if(this.bill[i]<50)
      this.tip[i]=0.2*this.bill[i];
      else
      this.tip[i]=0.1*this.bill[i];
      this.final[i]=this.tip[i]+this.bill[i];
    }
  }
};
```

I tried skipping the usage of 'this' to access array members of bill and this was the output that it produced :

---

Uncaught ReferenceError: bill is not defined

Comment: How are you calling the function? `john.calcTip()` works fine

Comment: If you want to use any object key-values inside the  function defined in same object you need it access from this keyword because here this hold the whole context of that object.

Comment: The error is not reproducible with the code you’ve shared. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function like `john.calcTip()` then JavaScript replaces `this` with the value stored in `john` inside the function `calcTip`. Basically any value before the `.` attached to a function call is the value of `this` inside the function.

If you do not want to use `this` inside the function `calcTip` you can replace `this` with `john` like:

```
var john=
 {  fullname: 'john smith',
  bill:[124,48,268,180,42],
  tip:[],final:[],
  calcTip:function()
  {
    for(var i =0;i<john.bill.length;i++)
    {
     if(john.bill[i]<50)
     john.tip[i]=0.2*john.bill[i];
     else
     john.tip[i]=0.1*john.bill[i];
    john.final[i]=john.tip[i]+john.bill[i];
    }
  }
```

};